# How can I stop faker gem from failing username uniqueness validation in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

Using faker to populate my database with fake users and I have a validation rule that makes sure usernames are unique and can't be registered more than once.

When I run rake db:populate it never reaches 1000 it stops sometime before it gets there and because I'm using create! it shows me what I need to see which is: Usernname has already been registered.

My question is there a way I can add a number to the username and each time it comes back round the number increases? That way no username will ever be the same.

e.g.

john1
pete2
sally3
smith4
luke5
john6
sally7

etc...

or is there some other way to make sure no username comes up more than once?

```
 namespace :db do
      namespace :development do
        desc "Create user records in the development database."
        task :populate => :environment do
          require 'faker'

          1000.times do

            User.create!(
            :username => Faker::Internet.user_name,
            :email => Faker::Internet.email,
            :password => "greatpasswordhuh"
    )


          end
        end
      end
    end
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me.
Not quite sure why "n" creates numbers though.

```
 namespace :db do
        desc "Create user records in the development database."
        task :populate => :environment do
          require 'faker'

          100.times do |n|
            username = "#{Faker::Name.first_name}#{n}"
            User.create!(
              :username => username,
              :email => Faker::Internet.email,
              :password => "greatpasswordhuh"
            )

        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: The "n" values are numbers, because "100.times" evaluates to numbers in Ruby.  If you had \@transactions = Transaction.all, and then \@transaction do |t|, then the 't' values in the block would be Transaction objects.

Answer (score 10):

You could add an index to your loop.

```
1000.times do |n|
  username = Faker::Internet.user_name
  username = "#{username}_#{n}"
  ...
end
```

Comment: I'm not understanding that, can you explain/show detailed example please? If you don't mind.

Comment: `times` is a method that takes a block and passes the a number, incremented each time the block is executed, into the block--you could call it anything, `n`, `number`, `count`. If you are not familiar with Ruby blocks, check out [this article](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_blocks.html) (and more--search for `ruby blocks` on Google).

Comment: Why would you separate those lines, instead of just doing username = "#{Faker::Internet_user_name}_#{n}"?

Comment: @jason Simply clarity/contrast with the code in the question.